# Only fill NAN values if there is 24 consecutives NAN or more

Tags: python, pandas

I have a really large dataframe and I'm trying to fill the blanks of some specific values with the mean of before and after non-nan values. Here is the thing: I have a lot of blanks, so I'd like to apply this rule only for rows up to 24 consecutive blanks. If there is > 24 (which there is plenty as well) I want to leave it as it is.

First I tried this:

```
df = df.interpolate(limit=24)
```

But it does not work the way I want to. For example, if I have 34 nan consecutive values, this code will fill until the 24th element and leave the other 10 unchanged.

Also, trying:

```
df["speed"] = df["speed"].transform(lambda x: x.fillna((df["speed"].ffill()+df["speed"].bfill())/2, limit=24))
```

It also does not work. Even only 1 or 2 consecutive NaNs have not been replaced. Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try:

```
s = df['speed']
s.interpolate()\
 .mask((s.groupby(s.notna().cumsum()).transform('size') - 1).where(s.isna()) > 24)
```

Comment: Hey @Scott Boston, thank you for your time! I tried your answer but it didn't work. Seems like the series is unchanged, because the 24-less consecutive blanks stil blanks as so the > 24.

Comment: Did you reassign s?  s=s.interpolate().....  print(s)? Well df['speed'] = s.interpolate......

Comment: @PedrodeSá Create a dummy set of data so I can test on.  thanks.  We can even lower the limit to 5 and see if works on a dummy set of data.

Comment: I'm so sorry, Scott, you're perfectly right! I completly forgot to reassign s. Your answer works correctly! Thank you so much!!